# What does clicking the "party hat" do when visiting someone's park?

Tags: dragonvale

When visiting a friend's park, I sometimes see a "party hat" over a friend's dragon dens.  If I click it, coins fly out.  What does that do?  Am I getting coins for myself, or my friend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get coins for it, your friend doesn't. For some reason it's always somewhere between 500 and 7,500 coins per party hat. Your level seems to determine how many coins you get. As Ebongo says it appears to be *roughly* X<sup>2</sup> * 10 coins where X is your level, but not exactly.

The coins respawn daily and friends with more habitats have more chances to have coins, but the max seems to be around 5 party hats per friend. It's just a little bonus to encourage you to visit your friends daily.

Comment: Just noted that for me the coins were 880 each time. Maybe it is level based?

Comment: It's level based I have like 4800 per party hat. It also gives 3 not 5.

Comment: Edited, if anyone knows lower/higher values let me known so I can work out the range.

Comment: It appears to be X squared * 10, where X is your level.  I got 3610 for level 19, now getting 4000 for level 20.  The above commented values would not fit with that formula though, so maybe it isn't the same equation for all levels.